# How to restore last values of listview and other views after coming app from foreground?

Tags: android, listview, foreground, onresume

When i click home button and then come back to to my application it doesn't show the last values on the listview or any other view it just look same with when i started the application.I believe it is can be done with onResume and onPause but i couldn't find how .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple ways to do this:

1. An SQLite database
2. Store the data as a file on the SD card.
3. SharedPreferences for the activity.
4. As a static variable in the Application class.

[Switching between Android activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682746/switching-between-android-activities)

Had asked the same question some time back.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all values in `SharedPreferences` in `onPause`, and then load them again in `onResume` and populate your views using that data.

Answer (score 0):

To get a full understanding, read about activity lifecycles and saving activity state [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actlife).